# Programming Console Error

Tags: c, file-io

```
#include<stdio.h>
void  main()
{
    do
    {
        char i;
        FILE *f,*q;
        f=fopen("E:\\txt.txt","w");
        while((i=getchar())!='\n')
        {
            fputc(i,f);
        }
        fclose(f);
        q=fopen("E:\\txt.txt","r");
        while((i=fgetc(q)!=EOF))
        {
            printf("%c",i);
        }
    } while(1);
}
```

It should output what pressed from keyboard but outputs to question boxes of same length of character I entered. And text is there where I specified in correct form. Below is the output after running the program.

[image]

Comment: FWIW, for the user's sake, implement a way to break out of the outer loop (e.g. empty string, or whatever you can come up with). Or get rid of the while loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The placement of parentheses in this line is wrong:

```
while ((i = fgetc(q) != EOF)) {
```

Because of operator precedence (in C, assigment operators have the lowest precedence), this is equivalent to

```
while (i = (fgetc(q) != EOF));
```

in other words, you are assigning `TRUE` to `i` each time, until you reach the end of the file. If you display that as `char`, you get a funny unprintable character, so you get a line of funny characters, but of the correct length.

It should be:

```
while ((i = fgetc(q)) != EOF) {
```

Then you should get your desired output.

Comment: @BinodThakur: if that works for you (it certainly does for me), you should accept this answer (click the V-shaped icon below the up/down votes at the left of the answer -- if it turns green, you accepted).

Comment: Thank you very much Rudy Velthuis